# RMagickを用いて、画像に絵文字付きで文字を載せる方法

Tags: ruby

表題の通り、
RMagickを用いて、画像に絵文字付きで文字を載せる方法 を知りたいです。

下記リファレンスを参考に文字を載せることはできているのですが、
などの絵文字を追加すると、表示されません。
調べても情報が少なく解決策が見つからないので、もしご存知の方いらっしゃればご教示頂けると幸いです。

参考：https://rmagick.github.io/draw.html#annotate

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問 - [Is it possible to render multi-coloured emojis with ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32475060)